# 300 length array data process every second in React Native & Android

Tags: android, react-native, mqtt

I received data from the MQTT server. almost 250 rows in each second now I have to check each of the rows and store that in redux. now the problem is that the app is getting slow when I process the data and store it in redux. I already applied multiple processes but nothing helps

Basically, Data is collected via sensors and processed, to be sent to the MQTT-Server, we receive data from the Mqtt-server using the **React-native-mqtt** package, to make sense for real-world applications with intuitive UI and visual representation.

```
 var timestamp = []
var result = true

const onMessageArrived = async (theMessage, dispatch) => { 
const split = theMessage.payloadString.split(';')
if (timestamp.length > 0) {
result = JSON.stringify(split) != JSON.stringify(timestamp)
}

if (result) {
    if (split[0] == 'bms100') {
        'worklet';
        BMS100(split, dispatch)
        dispatch({
            type: CHANGE_BMS100, payload: true
        })
    }
    else if (split[0] == 'bms24') {
        'worklet';
        BMS24(split, dispatch)
        dispatch({
            type: CHANGE_BMS24, payload: true
        })
    }
    else if (split[0] == 'n2k') {
        'worklet';
        N2K(split, dispatch)
        dispatch({
            type: CHANGE_N2K, payload: true
        })
    }
    else if (split[0] == 'motor') {
        'worklet';
        Motor(split, dispatch)
        dispatch({
            type: CHANGE_MOTOR, payload: true
        })
    }
    else if (split[0] == 'modbus') {
        'worklet';
        Modus(split, dispatch)
        dispatch({
            type: CHANGE_MODBUS, payload: true
        })
    } else {
        dispatch({
            type: FALSE_HEART_BEAT, payload: true
        })
    }
}

timestamp = split
}
```

The above is my main function when every, for example, I received modus from MQTT if called Modus() function and pass the data and there is 2 to 3 condition stored in REDUX

I hope you will help me. I appreciate your help

Thank you

```
export const Modus = (split, dispatch) => {
  if (split[0] == 'modbus' && split[1] == 'lower_deck_bb') {
    if (
      store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.washingMachine != booleanRev(split[3])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEFT_WASHING_MACHINE,
        payload: booleanRev(split[3]),
      });
    }
    if (
      store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.grayWaterPump != booleanRev(split[4])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEFT_GRAY_WATER_PUMP,
        payload: booleanRev(split[4]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.toilet != booleanRev(split[5])) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEFT_TOLIT,
        payload: booleanRev(split[5]),
      });
    }


 if (store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.ventilation != booleanRev(split[6])) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEFT_VENTILATION,
        payload: booleanRev(split[6]),
      });
    }
    if (
      store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.bilgepumpcenter != booleanRev(split[8])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEF_BILGE_PUMP_CENTER,
        payload: booleanRev(split[8]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.boiler != booleanRev(split[9])) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEFT_BOILER,
        payload: booleanRev(split[9]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.aircon != booleanRev(split[10])) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEFT_AIR_CON,
        payload: booleanRev(split[10]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.waterpump != booleanRev(split[7])) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEFT_WATER_PUMP,
        payload: booleanRev(split[7]),
      });
    }
    if (
      store.getState().LowerDeckLeftBtn.bilgepumpaft != booleanRev(split[11])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: SYSTEM_MAIN_LEFT_BLIGE_AFT,
        payload: booleanRev(split[11]),
      });
    }

    if (
      store.getState().LowerDeckRightBtn.ventilation != booleanRev(split[6])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWERDECK_RIGHT_VENTILATION,
        payload: booleanRev(split[6]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckRightBtn.aircon != booleanRev(split[10])) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWERDECK_RIGHT_AIRCON,
        payload: booleanRev(split[10]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckRightBtn.toilet != booleanRev(split[5])) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWERDECK_RIGHT_TOLIT,
        payload: booleanRev(split[5]),
      });
    }
    if (
      store.getState().LowerDeckRightBtn.grayWaterPump != booleanRev(split[4])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWERDECK_RIGHT_GRAY_WATER_PUMP,
        payload: booleanRev(split[4]),
      });
    }
    if (
      store.getState().LowerDeckRightBtn.bilgepumpaft != booleanRev(split[11])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWERDECK_RIGHT_BILGE_PUMP_AFT,
        payload: booleanRev(split[11]),
      });
    }
    if (
      store.getState().LowerDeckRightBtn.bilgepumpcenter != booleanRev(split[8])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWERDECK_RIGHT_BILGE_PUMP_CENTER,
        payload: booleanRev(split[8]),
      });
    }
  }

  else if (split[0] == 'modbus' && split[1] == 'switches') {
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckSwitch.lightSBB != booleanRev(split[3])) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWER_DECK_LIGHT_BB,
        payload: booleanRev(split[3]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckSwitch.lightSTB != booleanRev(split[4])) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWER_DECK_LIGHT_STB,
        payload: booleanRev(split[4]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().LowerDeckSwitch.outletsBB != booleanRev(split[5])) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWER_DECK_OUTLETS_BB,
        payload: booleanRev(split[5]),
      });
    }

    if (store.getState().LowerDeckSwitch.outletsstb != booleanRev(split[6])) {
      dispatch({
        type: LOWER_DECK_OUTLETS_STB,
        payload: booleanRev(split[6]),
      });
    }
    

    if (store.getState().UpperDeckSwitch.lightsalon != booleanRev(split[7])) {
      dispatch({
        type: UPPER_DECK_LIGHT_SALON,
        payload: booleanRev(split[7]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().UpperDeckSwitch.outletsalon != booleanRev(split[8])) {
      dispatch({
        type: UPPER_DECK_OUTLETS_SALON,
        payload: booleanRev(split[8]),
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().UpperDeckSwitch.lightOutside != booleanRev(split[9])) {
      dispatch({
        type: UPPER_DECK_LIGHT_OUTSIDE,
        payload: booleanRev(split[9]),
      });
    }
    if (
      store.getState().UpperDeckSwitch.navEquipment != booleanRev(split[10])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: UPPER_DECK_NAV_EQUIPMENT,
        payload: booleanRev(split[10]),
      });
    }
  } else if (split[0] == 'modbus' && split[1] == 'status') {
    if (store.getState().WaterDieselEvent.freshWaterbb != split[5]) {
      dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_FRESHWATER_BB,
        payload: split[5],
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().WaterDieselEvent.freshwaterstb != split[4]) {
      dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_FRESHWATER_STB,
        payload: split[4],
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().WaterDieselEvent.blackwaterbb != split[7]) {
      dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_BLACKWATER_BB,
        payload: split[7],
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().WaterDieselEvent.blackwaterstb != split[6]) {
      dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_BLACKWATER_STB,
        payload: split[6],
      });
    }
    if (store.getState().WaterDieselEvent.diesel != split[8]) {
      dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_DIESEL,
        payload: split[8],
      });
    }
    if (
      store.getState().GeneratorAndPower.GeneratorSwitch != booleanRev(split[3])
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: CHANGE_GENERATOR_SWITCH,
        payload: booleanRev(split[3]),
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Here is the Modus Function

Comment: There isn't actually a question here (there is an implied performance problem, but not enough infomration to give a proper answer, e.g. what would be an acceptable level of performance?). You also mention a `Modus()` function but it is not present anywhere in the code you have provided.

Comment: And you haven't really added any more details from when you last asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73972614/300-length-array-data-process-every-second-in-react-native

Comment: I added the Modus Function, please check the above code. For Example, When the onMessageArrived() function is called, if the data is related to Modus, it goes to Modus Function, and after the if-else statement executes. So there are too many if-else statements and every time it checks or goes through these if-else statements. I exactly Don't Know what function slows my app when data reaches to 250 rows in one second. In one second, it checks all the data from these if-else statements. and then store it in Redux. That's Why my app is slowing from time to time whenever the processing speed is fa

Comment: (modus;name=position_rapid_update;pgn=129025;sa=32;latitude=53.617543;longitude=10.3929734;lat_deg=53;lat_min=37;lat_sec=3.1548;lat_dir=North;long_deg=10;)   ***************                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Here is the Data format which we receive from MQTT-Server, we split it. after that, you see the above code for better understanding, If any confusion please let me know. Kindly please help, I am stuck in that very badly